# How can i make 2 Ovals follow and circle around another Oval when 'S' is pressed?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a game where you are an oval and **you have 2 ovals following you.** When you press 's' **the 2 ovals following you circle around you.** The problem is that I can't make the ovals do a 360 turn.

Code:

```
public class apples extends JFrame {

public static int x, y;
public static int userWIDTH = 15;
public static int userHEIGHT = 15;
public static int defenseWIDTH = 5;
public static int defenseHEIGHT = 5;
public static int defenseX;
public static int defenseY;

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
            if(!(x < 15)) {
                x += -10;
            }
        }

        else if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            if(!(x > 810)) {
                x += 10;
            }
        }

        else if(keyCode == e.VK_S) {
            //Not sure how to make the 2 ovals circle while following the player.
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}

public apples() {
    super("Dodgem");
    setSize(840, 620);
    setResizable(true);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addKeyListener(new AL());

    x = (this.getWidth() - (userWIDTH + userHEIGHT)) / 2;
    y = (this.getHeight() - (userWIDTH + userHEIGHT)) / 2;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(x, y, userWIDTH, userHEIGHT);
        defenseX = x;
        defenseY = y;
        g.fillOval(defenseX - 20, defenseY + 20, defenseWIDTH, defenseHEIGHT);
        g.fillOval(defenseX + 20, defenseY - 20, defenseWIDTH, defenseHEIGHT);
        repaint();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new apples();
}
```

Also, this is an example if it helps...
The two ovals have to "spin".

[image]

Sorry for my ignorance, and in advance, thank you.

Comment: Can you show us, what you have tried so far?

Comment: else if(keyCode == e.VK_S) {
    defenseX -= 10;
    defenseY += 10;
   }

Comment: It wouldnt complete the turn and would not position itself correctly. And it would not work since i have "defenseX = x; defenseY = y;" in paintComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make something move in a cricle around a point you need to use the parametric equation for a circle. It is described fully on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle

The equation can be written in parametric form using the trigonometric functions sine and cosine as:

```
x = a + r cos t
y = b + r sin t
```

where `t` is a parametric variable in the range 0 to 2π, interpreted geometrically as the angle that the ray from (a, b) to (x, y) makes with the x-axis.

In other words, if your target is at (a,b) then to circle around it with radius `r` you need to plug those variables into the equations above, with `t` being the angle between 0 and 2π that you want the chaser to be at.

If you want the chaser to transition between chasing and circling then you will need to determine the starting angle using elementary trigonometry.